# How to update table schema in sqlite.net on windows 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

How do I update the schema of an existing table in a Windows 8 Store app that is using Sqlite.net?  I tried `CreateTableAsync` however that creates a new table, losing existing data. It is supposed to update the schema on insert; however when I try to insert data for a column that is not in the table it crashes indicating that the column doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you tried using the SQLite Database Browser <http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/>? It provides an easy-to-use GUI for all simple database manipulations.

Comment: Can you show the code your using? I tried both CreateTable as well as CreateTableAsync and if I add one property to my table class and call CreateTable it adds it to the table with null values for the existing records and adds values if I thereafter start inserting records.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.Update` instead of creating a new table. The `.Update` wil create a new database by the hand of your provided Model and copy/paste al the existing data over to the new database.

My code for checking and updating my database

```
if(result.FirstOrDefault().version != 3  || result.FirstOrDefault().version == 0)
{
    //Update Database with new columns by the updated model called Unlockables

    conn.CreateTable<Unlockables>();
    try
    {
        var existingRow = (conn.Table<Unlockables>().Where(c => c.Id == 1)).SingleOrDefault();
        existingRow.version = 3;
        existingRow.SelectedTheme = 0;
        existingRow.Theme1 = true;
        int succes = conn.Update(existingRow);
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Hope that will help :)